# Angular displacement and the displacement vector

Tags: vectors, displacement

I've been recently introduced to angular displacement, and I'm a little bit confused about it. I think that *displacement* which is a vector and which is defined as the shortest distance between any two points is different from *angular displacement*. Angular displacement is measured in radian or in other words it measures the 'angle' that a rotating body goes through. However, *displacement vector* is measured in meter. Angular displacement has the dimension of $1$; however, displacement vector has the dimension $L$. Is there any concept of the-shortest-distance-covered in angular displacement? I think angular displacement may just mean the change of position of a rotating body w.r.t. the angle subtended by the arc, traveled by it, at the center of the circle around which it is rotating.

[image]

If a body is rotating about the axis of a circle, and it moves from point A to B making an arc of length S, then the distance it covered is given by $S = θr$. However, the shortest distance it could have covered to reach point B can be given by the length of the vector D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first-
Angular displacement is quite different from displacement. It has **dimension 1** as its unit is radians(plane angle), which is not a fundamental unit. Not only that but I think that it is not the change in $\theta$ but actually the total $\theta$ travelled.

For example, if some particle moves in a complete circle and stops at its initial position, its angular displacement is actually $2\pi$, and not 0.

And thus if you multiply $\theta$ with R, you get distance travelled by the particle and not its displacement. 
You can always find the displacement too, I guess.

*Example:* A particle has angular displacent $5\cdot \pi$ in time $t$. Find its displacement in time $t$.

We keep subtracting $2\cdot \pi$ until 
$$0 \leq θ < 2\cdot\pi$$

(we do this to cancel out the full circles travelled by the particle as when it completes a circle its displacement becomes 0)

thus we know it travelled 2 full circles and then pi radians.
Thus the displacement = $2r$

Answer (score 2):

You have to rotate it, you cannot just move every point across your vector $\vec D$, that would be a simple displacement. I would think of it as winding up a spring (like in a clock) and noting how many revolutions I have wound it up. And I would measure that in radian (or without a unit, if you like).

Comment: Why do we call it 'displacement' anyways?

Comment: Since it can be positive and negative, and rolls back, if you turn into the opposite direction. Your one dimensional rotation is like a one dimensional displacement. Say you move only in the $x$-direction.